# Test result caching using --test_env

Tags: bazel

Is there a way to mark certain `--test_env` values to not affect the cacheability of test results?

I have a scenario where there exists a fixed pool of `n` test resources. I've set the level of test parallelization to be no more than the size of this pool using `--local_test_jobs=n`. The resources are managed by a small daemon that is launched before calling `bazel test`. The port for this daemon is passed in using `--test_env`. Unless we want to use a fixed port number, each time we pass a different port number in, `bazel test` will refuse to use cached test results as the action environment has changed.

Is this possible? If not, is there some other mechanism that can provide a similar functionality?

Answer (score 1):

If you could make e.g. a network call to get the port number from the test, and do the call during the test, you don't have to pass port number using --test_env and all the test runs will be properly cached. Does it make sense?

Comment: A network call to where? This is all on one machine. It's talking to a port on localhost. Maybe some zeroconf service discovery sort of thing?

Comment: You want to make the test not depend on test_env. I'm suggesting hardcoding the port number in the test. But since you probably want to have it configurable, e.g. to run multiple tests with multiple daemons, it's better to add another service (socket, file,...) that will tell the test which port number for daemon to use.

I'm suggesting making the test less hermetic, for the things you don't want to be hermetic.